# HTML5 Changing paragraphs background color with button js

Tags: javascript, html

I got small troubles with this one:

```
<style>
p:empty {height:20px};
p:nth-child(4n+3) {background:black};
</style>    
</head>

<body>

<button onclick="f()">white</button>
<script>
function f() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
....
```

(there are 20paragraphs)
So every 4th paragraph got black background, and it all works well.
I want this button to switch black back to the white after clicking on it, but it's just not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to loop/iterate though those elements. The clue is in the selector. getElement**s**ByTagName - get element(S) so it returns a group/collection of elements. Here is a [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/54hk1cuh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you are using getElementsByTagName which will return you an array of all the instances of the "p" element. There for when you say
x.style.backgroundColor = "white"

you need to specify which "p" in your array you want to change, like I have below
x[3].style.backgroundColor = "white"

... you can probably do something like this

```
function f() {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i=0; i<x.length; i=i+4) {

 x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, you'll want to iterate through the elements. That's quite simple to do, just use a `forEach` as shown below.

```
function f() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    Array.from(x).forEach(elem => elem.style.backgroundColor = "white");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually **[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** will return a `HTMLCollection`, you need to loop over it and apply the style:

```
function f() {
  var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  Array.from(paragraphs).forEach(function(x){
       x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function f() {
  var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  Array.from(paragraphs).forEach(function(x){
       x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });
}
```

```css
p:empty {
  height: 20px;
}

p:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f()">white</button>

<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your function `f` makes the  call `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`. `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection` object, which does not have a `style` property, and setting it wont do anything. What you want to do is iterate through the items of the `HTMLCollection` and set the style for each element, like so:

```
// This function will make all <p> elements have a white background
function f() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

For more information see Mozilla's documentation for [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).